# How to run specific methods infinite time in background per 5 seconds in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am developing a Vaccine Viewer app and I want to implement a function that run till vaccine get available.

Here is my vaccine checker method

```
boolean checkVaccine(String pinCode,String data){
    isVaccineAvailable = false;
    String url = "https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/calendarByPin?pincode="+pinCode+"&date="+data;

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {

                        JSONArray dataArray = response.getJSONArray("centers");

                        if(dataArray.length()==0){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No Center Available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        for(int i=0;i<dataArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject centers = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String centerName = centers.getString("name");
                            String centerAddress = centers.getString("address");
                            String vaccinationStartTime = centers.getString("from");
                            String vaccinationEndTime = centers.getString("to");
                            String vaccinePrice = centers.getString("fee_type");

                            JSONObject sessions = centers.getJSONArray("sessions").getJSONObject(0);
                            int minimumAge = sessions.getInt("min_age_limit");
                            String vaccineName = sessions.getString("vaccine");
                            int totalVaccineAvailable = sessions.getInt("available_capacity");

                            if(totalVaccineAvailable>0){
                                isVaccineAvailable = true;
                            }

                            vaccinationData addData = new vaccinationData(centerName,
                                    centerAddress,vaccinationStartTime,vaccinationEndTime,
                                    vaccinePrice,vaccineName,totalVaccineAvailable,minimumAge);

                            dataList.add(addData);

                        }

                        vaccinationDataAdapter adapter = new vaccinationDataAdapter(MainActivity.this,dataList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Unable To Get Data From Server.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Unable To Get Data From Server.\nMake Sure Your Internet Connection ON.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    queue.add(request);
    return isVaccineAvailable;
}
```

I want to run above methods till function not return true. I was searched but I am unable to understand what exact I have to use? And How ?

There are **Handler, TimerTask, Runnable** to repeat a task after few seconds
and I got Job Scheduler but that need api <=21 And I want to give support for <=18, but I am not getting How to do this in background?

I tried below Code in MainActivity, but after calling that app get stuck and restart. I am beginner in android development, I dont know much more about service, and broadcast receiver.

```
while(!checkVaccine(pinCode,date)){
                    Handler waitForFiveSeconds = new Handler();
                    waitForFiveSeconds.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                        }
                    },5000);
                    dataList.clear();
                }

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Vaccine Is AVailable.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                notifyToTheUser();
```

***What I have to use to repeat **checkVaccine method** forever in background after every 5 Seconds?***

Comment: what do you mean "in background"? as a daemon thread?

Comment: @Stultuske In the background sense If user clicked on Notify Me button then vaccine checker methods run till it does not return true and show notification even application is minimized.

Comment: haven't written any android apps yet, so I may be off, but I don't see why being minimized should impact the functionality of an app

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is background service. You can run operation in a background service for a long time. As you want to run these infinitely, this won't work as android has put some limitations prior Android O so your service would be stopped at some point

These are some articles on how to create it and it's limitations

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-background-service-in-android

https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-to-handle-background-services-in-android-o-f96783e65268

This is not a good approach to run any task infinitely in the background and indeed it is a bad practice. This will drain battery and system resources.

You want to build something which notifies you when vaccines get available for a certain Pincode, you should build something which runs on servers and sends you a notification when it is available, not your device checking every 5 seconds for it.

You could build a Telegram bot and deploy your application on a service like Heroku or AWS.

I want to let you know, that cowin API is Geo-Restricted so if you built something server-side it won't work at all if you choose any instance that is not located in India, You need an Indian server instance to make this work.

Comment: I want to run locally check Vaccine methods many time as app running in device.

Comment: There is any way to run method many times.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of my answer by watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfQE1ayCzf8).

I have to use **Thread Or Runnable Interface** to do that in background.